# Trying to get json data with php

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, feed

I am trying to get data from a json file to be loaded into my wordpress site. I would like to get the price from the matching name of the product of the site that I crawled. I need the name of the product to match the product attribute I added into the product page on wordpress then to get the price if the name matches the attribute I added. The code below partially worked, but for some reason the call for the attribute is not working. Any advice?

```
    $str = file_get_contents('/run_results_apmex.json');

// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// default value
$coinPrice = "No results found";
$product_attribute = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id , 'pa_apmex' );
// loop the json array
foreach($json['coin'] as $value){
    // check the condition
    if($value['name'] == trim($product_attribute)){ 
        $coinPrice = $value['price']; // get the price 
        break; // exit the loop
    }
}

echo $coinPrice;
```

Comment: check you json isn't valid i guess http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The json is valid. Checked it again just to be sure.

Comment: can you add a var_dump($str); after the file_get_contents i want show  just the parents nodes to be sure and if is to not long.

Comment: Can you please provide the json string too.

Comment: Here is the file': http://gold.explorethatstore.com/wp-content/themes/divi-ETS-child-theme/run_results_apmex.json

Comment: The problem is with `wc_get_product_terms` try to `echo` its output. And post that too.

Comment: not sure what you mean with this. Sorry I am a newbie on php

Comment: Try `echo wc_get_product_terms( $product->id , 'pa_apmex' );` and post the output here.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried that and it broke the entire page.

Comment: I did the echo in a different div and it pulled "Array" which is not the value of the attribute I am looking to call

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced your function call

`$product_attribute = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id , 'pa_apmex' );`

with

```
$product_attribute = '2017 Canada 1 oz Gold Maple Leaf BU';
```

and ran the code

```
    $str = file_get_contents('run_results_apmex.json');

// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// default value
$coinPrice = "No results found";
$product_attribute = '2017 Canada 1 oz Gold Maple Leaf BU';
// loop the json array
foreach ($json['coin'] as $value) {
    // check the condition
    if ($value['name'] == trim($product_attribute)) {
        $coinPrice = $value['price']; // get the price
        break; // exit the loop
    }
}

echo $coinPrice;
```

Echo displayed "$1,316.09". So, json seems working fine. I'd var_dump  **wc_get_product_terms($product->id , 'pa_apmex')** and see what it returns.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried that as well a few different ways and it just does not work. When I var_dump that I get "array(0)" It is really unusual. To help open my options I installed avanced custom fields and tried making the $product_attribute = the_field('apmex_vendor_name'); and that does pull in the value of that field, but it displays it next to "No Result Found" on the front end. This is all pretty odd.